# A little bit complicated NSPredicate (IOS)ha

Tags: ios, nested, nspredicate, one-to-many

Now, I need to use a predicate for a NSFetchRequest.

But things here are a little different, since there are **two** nested **to-many** relationships for the predicate to go through.

For instance, my entities are like this:

[image]

Now I need to fetch some Month and Week ManagedObjects, but the requirement is that the amount of Events of a Day of the needed Weeks or Months is more than one.

In another word, with reference to a given Week or Month, if any Day on the destination of its "days" relationship has at least one Event, then take it.

So that is a nested to-many relationship, and I don't know how to set the predicate string.

There are two troubles:

1. I know ALL and ANY keyword. But could `@"ANY days.ANY events"` be the keypath? Or how is it supposed to be?
2. How to judge that the events relationship points to at least one Event object.

Would `[@"%K != nil",theCorrectKeypath]` work? I'm afraid of that "!= nil" does not equal to at least one destination object?

Waiting for someone to help me out.

Terribly thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self.

There's another way to get this, because of my condition, I can just predicate the suitable Events objects, and all the way from Events to Week or Month are to-one relationship,

so once I got the eligible Events,

I can just get corresponding Weeks and Months by

theEvent.date.thisWeek or theEvent.date.thisMonth.

Thanks for your guys,